# Using Table-Valued Functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm sorry for I'm not very good at English.

My T-SQL function:

```
create function sumofOrder(@thang int, @nam int)
returns table 
as
return 
    SELECT        
        Sales.SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID, 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate, 
        SUM(Sales.SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty * Sales.SalesOrderDetail.UnitPrice) AS SubTotal
    FROM            
        Sales.SalesOrderDetail 
    INNER JOIN
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader ON Sales.SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID
    GROUP BY 
        Sales.SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID, 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate
    HAVING        
        (SUM(Sales.SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty * Sales.SalesOrderDetail.UnitPrice) > 70000) 
        AND YEAR(Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate) = @nam 
        AND MONTH(Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate) = @thang
```

And now, I want to use it for filtering by @thang and @nam and not any specific values.

Example of a scalar function:

```
select 
    [DepartmentID], [Name], dbo.cau1([DepartmentID]) as 'tongnhanvien' 
from 
    [HumanResources].[Department]
```

Thank you everyone!
ps: my idea is: `select * from [dbo].[sumofOrder](MONTH(Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate), YEAR(Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate))`

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Right now your question is not clear. Not because of your english but because you fail to mention what is the problem, what you want to do with your function or your query. It is just missing information.

Comment: You use `CROSS APPLY`([documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)) for this purpose to get the data from your function BUT the function needs to be called with the same parameters that is created. As it looks like, you will need to add a `@DepartmentId` as a parameter to your function and when cross applying, you will need to pass all three params to the function.

Comment: @Jorge Campos Tôi muốn sử dụng nó như sau: `select * from [dbo]. [SumofOrder] (MONTH (Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate), YEAR (Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate))`

Comment: @Rigerta Demiri bạn có thể cho tôi một mẫu mã

Comment: Sorry man, don't understand your language. English please.

Answer (score 0):

[Table-Valued User-Defined Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx)

simply select from it:

```
select * from sumofOrder(thangValue, namValue)
```

Also [Using APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)

> The APPLY operator allows you to invoke a table-valued function for
>   each row returned by an outer table expression of a query. The
>   table-valued function acts as the right input and the outer table
>   expression acts as the left input. The right input is evaluated for
>   each row from the left input and the rows produced are combined for
>   the final output. The list of columns produced by the APPLY operator
>   is the set of columns in the left input followed by the list of
>   columns returned by the right input.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT f.*
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader s
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[sumofOrder](month(s.OrderDate), year(s.OrderDate)) f
```

Comment: my idea is: select * from [dbo].[sumofOrder](MONTH(Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate), YEAR(Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate))

Comment: Thank you so much! cảm ơn nhiều!

Comment: Do you know how to formally accept the answer, or at least upvote it?